# Issue in carousel implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to implement carousel on my web page.I have created a plunker page for the same.
In that link, i have used CSS3 transformations to create circle effects.

In the above link i have removed the code which i had for carousel implementation because it was not working.Actually what happens is that  most of the jquery caosuel available like(elastslide,liquidcarosel,flexslider) etc work  only if the img(which needs to be slided) is directly under "li" tag.But in my case, i can't keep img directly under "li" because of the css3 transformations i need.(See index.html page)
http://plnkr.co/edit/PxTtJ2expidIamWUqXLj?p=preview&s=carousel
for eg

```
<li>
 <div class="ch-item">   
 <div class="ch-info ch-info1" >                            
 </div>
 <div class="ch-thumb ch-img-1">
 <p class="text"> Java7</p>
 </div>
 </div>
 </li>
```

Could anyone please suggest how can i implement it.

Comment: Markup is not correct. You should not use <div> tag into <ul> tag.

Comment: @aplesh...Why do you think so? I have seen html code where div are used inside <li> or ul. Is there any particular reason you said so?Even if, lets assume you are correct, how do i even solve my original problem? i mean i have put my code in plunker sit(link shared in my oriignal post) for you reference